# Wait for 2 methods to complete Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, wait, sequential, subscribe

I have two methods that return two different arrays using REST requests provided in services logic:

```
 cartItemNodes: TreeNode[] = [];
 cartGroupNodes: TreeNode[] = [];

 getCartItems(){
  //subscribe to service observable filling the array 
  return this.cartItemNodes;
}

 getCartGroups(){
  //subscribe to service observable filling the array 
  return this.cartGroupNodes;
}
```

How can I build a *third method*

> getCartFinalNodes()

**which** waits until the first **two** are completed and then combines their results into a single array?

```
getCartFinalNodes(){
//wait for first 2 methods
return this.cartItemNodes.concat(this.cartGroupNodes);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firstly return promises from your two methods then use `Promise.all` like following

```
  Promise.all([
   firstMethod(key1),
   seondMethod(key2),
  ]).then(value => thirdMethod());
```

Comment: how can one return promises in this scenario?

Comment: you can do `firstMethod(): Promise<DataType>`  and within the finction return your data

Answer (score 2):

Use Promise API :

```
getCartItems() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(this.cartItemNodes);
    });
}

getCartGroups() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(this.cartGroupNodes);
    });
}

Promise.all([
    this.getCartItems(),
    this.getCartGroups(),
    ]).then(value => this.getCartFinalNodes());
```